# gdaladdo positive and negative aspects?

Tags: gdal

I read and I read opinions and topics regarding this tool but I am still unclear if I should us this or not.

In my project I have thousands off tiff files which need to be put on a map. The problem is that while creating the tiles (map tiles) it runs really slow, especially when it needs to put a lot of tiffs on a tile..

I heard that gdaladdo can speed this up but I am unsure if this could affect the quality of the tiff files and/or any other side effects.

Unfortunately, I do not have a backup for the files and while I was testing this on a few bunch of files, the only thing I saw was the increase in size for each of the files.

If anyone had positive (and especially negative) experiences using this tool, I would appreciate an example, advice or anything you think can help.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gdaladdo builds overviews internally by default.  That is why you have seen the increased file size.  You can build external overview by specifying:

```
gdaladdo -ro ...
```

This will build external overviews:

http://gdal.org/gdaladdo.html

As far as benefits, it depends on the application.  If the application uses gdal, then it is built in (for some drivers) to automatically use the overviews to speed up raster input/output.  See the docs here:

http://gdal.org/classGDALRasterBand.html#a5497e8d29e743ee9177202cb3f61c3c7

Answer (score 0):

gdaladdo adds overview (also called pyramids) to your file. Pyramids are additionnal information to your raster image, which can be seen as a stack of coarser and coarser resolution. Most application will be able to read the pyramids, selecting the most appropriate level of the pyramid to increase the display speed when you zoom out (without pyramids, the resampling at the screen resolution is performed "on the fly", which slows it down).

In terms of advantages/disadvantages, pyramids are often useful :

1. pyramids are additionnal information, this can be as heavy as 1/3 of the original image. So if you don't need to visualize the data, it is a **waste of storage** (especially if your data is already very large). On the other hand, pyramids do not affect the quality of the data (only what you see), they can be built externally (with -ro), compressed with lossy compressions for more efficiency, and removed if no more needed (with -clean)
2. pyramids increase the visualisation speed of many application, but are heavy to build. So don't build them if you always zoom to the finest resolution of the data. And note that for Web viewing, tiling could be an alternative.

As a remark, once you have pyramids, you can build cloud optimized tifs for even better perfomances (beter metadata structure).